# Laravel 4 and Paypal notify_url

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I'm currently using Laravel 4.2 but having a little issue with the Paypal "Buy Now Express" button (witch you can generate from paypal.com own website).

**The paypal button form looks like this,**

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" maethod="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input name="notify_url" value="http://www.domain.com/paypal" type="hidden">
    <input name="custom" value="iuhqd12e12d1712d71d" type="hidden" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://domain.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="KFKXE75DXMYNE">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

**Paypal Controller (this works, if i access it directly)**

```
class PaypalController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
       mail('mail@domain.com','test','test');
    }
}
```

**Route file looks like**

```
Route::resource('paypal', 'PaypalController');
```

When i acesss domain.com/paypal directly, the email is sent, but when i test it on paypal and my payment is completed in Paypal sandbox, it wont send any email? I tested the same configuration (with the same form setup) with just a simple index.php and mail.php (mail.php as notify_url) and my email got sent immediately. (note: the index.php and mail.php test was not in laravel, just pure php).

Am I doing something wrong here? Or does Laravel block Paypal from accessing the route? Is there any good way of debugging this? Nothing is showing in the error logs of Laravel.

Comment: Is there any filters active for that `Route` ?

Comment: Make sure you have IPN enabled in your profile.  You can override any value there with notify_url, but if it's not turned on it won't send anything at all.  If you still feel like it's not working, check the IPN History in PayPal to verify whether or not the IPN's are actually getting sent.